# Running Xcode Applications without installing Xcode

Tags: xcode

I know nothing about Xcode, except it's a Developer interface from Apple that actually comes on OSX CD and it's used to create iPhone apps as well.

I also know it have a Applications folder, filled with little utilities, that are indeed quite useful. I tried [grabbing one of them](https://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-mac/118504#118504) and running, without installing Xcode but it doesn't work. It brings an error and a Problem Report from which I believe the relevant part is this:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/DevToolsInterface.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsInterface
```

I've tried, of course, locating that "framework", with no success.

Well...

I guess it's probably possible to install Xcode, get that utility source, if it exists somewhere, and compile for stand-alone. But that goes beyond my point.

I just want to know if there's somewhere I can get those utilities and/or make them run without needing to install Xcode at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the developer tools depend on several shared frameworks that are installed in `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks` and `/Developer/Library/Frameworks` and several of the tools also depend on other files in the `/Developer/Library` folder.

The Apple developer tools are intended to be installed and used as a set.

Why not just install the developer tools? Is there a particular reason you don't want to do this? You can choose not to install the documentation and various other packages if you're worried about disk space.

Comment: Ok, that answers why it isn't working - as expected it's due to broken dependencies. I'm not all that worried about disk space, I will install XCode anyway, but I wanted to be able to get the FileMerge, and other tools, without needing to do that because if I want just a 1.5MB I didn't want to need to install 1.5GB. So I'm still hoping to know if there's a way to install any of them without installing XCode before I install it.

Comment: I'll just take this answers it as ***"it can't be easily done"***.

Comment: @jrodatus which answer?

Comment: @cregox, oops, sorry. I deleted it. embedding Xcode's OtherFrameworks/ and adding an RPATH let it launch stand-alone, but it crashed when you tried to compare files. I plan to look at it in a debugger later

Answer (score 4):

As the linked superuser entry says, those tools (such as FileMerge) are part of the XCode developer tools suite. They're not depending XCode as an application - just that they are bundled as part of the dev tools set.

Since the dev tools are free, you can freely download and use them if you want (you don't need to use XCode itself).

Alternatively there are other file compare/ merge tools. My favourite for the Mac is [Changes](http://connectedflow.com/changes/) (also mentioned in the superuser entry).

Comment: Why isn't what working? You said you hadn't installed XCode, didn't you? Or did you mean you installed the dev tools *except* for XCode?

Comment: @Phil You said those tools are not depending XCode as an application, that I don't need to use XCode itself. I haven't installed XCode nor dev tools. I simply grabbed one tool, the FileMerge.app, and it isn't working. It seems like a contradiction to me.

Comment: What I meant was, if you install the dev tools as a suite you'll get all the dependencies needed. You don't need to build anything, or use XCode it all - but it will be there (you may be able to deselect it in the install - have not tried that). Is there a particular reason you don't want to install the dev tools?

Comment: @Phil I just think those tools are simple enough that they would not need to install 1.5GB just to use them. In my specific case, I will install the Xcode, but since I didn't yet I'm trying to do it without installing. In particular, with that I can recommend the tools for more people who will most certainly not need the whole package and would be happy with just 1 or 2 MB. Specially nice if the FileMerge works fine.

Comment: @Cawas. I hear you. Personally I think FileMerge is just about good enough that it's nice to have it as part of the SDK install so you know you've always got it on an SDK inhabited machine - but if you wanted to install a standaline diff/ merge tool there are better ones you'd probably start with. That doesn't address your direct need but it's all I got :-) Sorry.

Comment: @Phil that's fine. The question here is pretty specific about XCode and nothing else, tho. Thanks for all your help! :)